# Storing arbitrary primitive types in an a java array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, primitive, primitive-types

I have a use case where I must parse JSON into primitive values in Java.  I have instructive fields embedded in the JSON that informs my parsing which primitive to deserialize to.  These primitive types must be added to an array of some length.

So I may have some JSON like this:

```
"primitives" : [
{
"valueType" : "int",
"value" : 3
},
{
"valueType" : "double",
"value" : 4
},
]
```

I have written the code to properly parse this JSON into two primitives, one int and double with values 3 and 4.  However, because I am adding them to an ArrayList which expects Objects they are autoboxed into Java's Integer and Double types.  I thought of using a regular Java Array but there is still the problem of specifying the element type like `Object[] arr` where I have the same problem, or `int[]` where I am being too specific.

Is there some functionality within Java that can allow me to parse this JSON to the correct Array of primitives.

One solution I have considered is an object that has all the different primitives as properties but this seems like too much complexity if a language level path is available.

Comment: How are you going to retrieve the values, since it seems like you would need to know the specific type? For example, `int value1 = SomeArray[0]`, and `double value2 = SomeArray[1]` seems like you would need to know the type of the value.

Comment: What is the problem with  `Object[] arr`?

Comment: Why don't you just use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) or an alternative JSON parser? You're reinventing the wheel and adding redundant type info to your JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it is important to keep the original ordering (thus a single array), and that keeping track of the type is important, and that using a JSON parser is unavailable, I would consider something like the following.

```
enum ValueType { INT, DOUBLE, FLOAT };

static abstract class ParsedValue<T>
{
    private final T data;
    private final ValueType type;

    public ParsedValue(T val, ValueType t)
    {
        data = val;
        type = t;
    }

    public ValueType getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        return data;
    }
}

static class IntParsedValue extends ParsedValue<Integer>
{
    public IntParsedValue(Integer val)
    {
        super(val, ValueType.INT);
    }
}

static class DoubleParsedValue extends ParsedValue<Double>
{
    public DoubleParsedValue(Double val)
    {
        super(val, ValueType.DOUBLE);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<ParsedValue<?>> lst = new ArrayList<>();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
        ParsedValue<?> pv;            
        if (rnd.nextInt(2) == 0) {
            pv = new IntParsedValue(rnd.nextInt(500));
        }
        else {
            pv = new DoubleParsedValue(rnd.nextDouble());
        }

        lst.add(pv);
    }

    for (ParsedValue<?> pv : lst) {
        switch (pv.getType()) {
        case INT:
            System.out.println("Integer: " + pv.getValue());
            break;

        case DOUBLE:
            System.out.println("Double: " + pv.getValue());
            break;

        case FLOAT:
            //...
            break;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: So you basically expanded on the idea I suggested at the end of my question.  Thank you for the help, I will most likely incorporate this into my approach.  The subclasses setting an enum is a nice touch I might not have thought of so I appreciate this answer.